# Why in JavaScript both "Object instanceof Function" and "Function instanceof Object" return true?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Why in JavaScript do both `Object instanceof Function` and `Function instanceof Object` return `true`?

I tried it in Safari WebInspector.

Comment: Functions are objects, not all objects are functions. Instance of checks work on instances - you're checking the constructors which are themselves functions.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what result you expected.

Comment: @cookiemonster - from the question, OP expected an isPrototypeOf check.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Where in the question do you see that?

Comment: In the subtext, from the fact OP is surprised that Object instanceof Function.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: OP is wants to know why an `instanceof` check returned `true` for both tests. I'm asking which one(s) he presumably expected to return `false`. There must be some misunderstanding of what one or both of the objects he's testing is. In other words, there was an expectation which was not met, so what specifically was that expectation.

Comment: Old thread, but this should explain it: https://javascriptrefined.io/function-and-object-instances-of-each-other-1e1095d5faac :)

Answer (score 40):

It took a while for me to figure out but its really worth the time spent. First, let us see how `instanceof` works.

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#Summary),

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the `prototype` property of a constructor.

#### `[instanceof]`

Now, let us see how [`instanceof`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.6) is defined by ECMA 5.1 Specification,

> The production `RelationalExpression: RelationalExpression instanceof ShiftExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `RelationalExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `ShiftExpression`.
> 4. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 5. If `Type(rval)` is not Object, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 6. If `rval` does not have a `[[HasInstance]]` internal method, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 7. Return the result of calling the `[[HasInstance]]` internal method of `rval` with argument `lval`.

First the left and right hand side expressions are evaluated (`GetValue`) and then right hand side result should be an Object with `[[HasInstance]]` internal method. Not all objects will have `[[HasInstance]]` internal method, but functions. For example, the following will fail

```
console.log(Object instanceof {});
# TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<Object>
```

#### `[[HasInstance]]`

Now, let us see how [`[[HasInstance]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.3) has been defined in the ECMA 5.1 specification,

> Assume `F` is a Function object.
>
> When the `[[HasInstance]]` internal method of `F` is called with value `V`, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If `V` is not an object, return `false`.
> 2. Let `O` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `F` with property name `"prototype"`.
> 3. If `Type(O)` is not Object, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 4. Repeat
>
>    1. Let `V` be the value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of `V`.
>    2. If `V` is `null`, return `false`.
>    3. If `O` and `V` refer to the same object, return `true`.

It is so simple. Take the `prototype` property of `F` and compare it with the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of `O` until it becomes `null` or `prototype` of `F` is the same as `O`.

#### `[[prototype]]` internal property

First let us see what is the [`[[prototype]]` internal property](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2),

> All objects have an internal property called `[[Prototype]]`. The value of this property is either `null` or an object and is used for implementing inheritance. Whether or not a native object can have a host object as its `[[Prototype]]` depends on the implementation. Every `[[Prototype]]` chain must have finite length (that is, starting from any object, recursively accessing the `[[Prototype]]` internal property must eventually lead to a `null` value).

**Note:** We can get this internal property with the [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.2) function.

#### `prototype` property

`[[HasInstance]]` also talks about another property called [`prototype`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.2), which is specific to the `Function` objects.

> The value of the `prototype` property is used to initialise the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of a newly created object before the Function object is invoked as a constructor for that newly created object.

This means that, when a function object is used as a constructor, a new object will be created and the new object will have its internal `[[Prototype]]` initialized with this `prototype` property. For example,

```
function Test() {}
Test.prototype.print = console.log;
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new Test()) === Test.prototype);
# true
```

#### Actual problem

Now let us get back to the actual question. Lets take the first case

```
console.log(Object instanceof Function);
# true
```

It will fetch `Function.prototype` first and it will try and find if that object is in the prototype hierarchy of `Object`. Let us see how that turns out

```
console.log(Function.prototype);
# [Function: Empty]
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object));
# [Function: Empty]
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Function.prototype);
# true
```

Since the `Function.prototype` matches the `Object`'s internal property `[[Prototype]]`, it returns `true`.

Now lets take the second case

```
console.log(Function instanceof Object);
# true
console.log(Object.prototype);
# {}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function));
# [Function: Empty]
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.prototype);
# false
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function)));
# {}
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function)) === Object.prototype
# true
```

Here, first we get the `Object.prototype`, which is `{}`. Now it is trying to find if the same object `{}` is there in the `Function`'s prototype chain. Immediate parent of `Function` is and Empty function.

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function));
# [Function: Empty]
```

It is not the same as `Object.prototype`

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.prototype);
# false
```

But the `[[HasInstance]]` algorithm doesn't stop there. It repeats and gets up one more level

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function)));
# {}
```

And this is the same as `Object.prototype`. That is why this returns `true`.

Comment: In case someone else is also confused by Object.getPrototypeOf here, you can also think of it as [Reflect.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/getPrototypeOf) which has been added to the spec in ES6.

Answer (score 15):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

Essentially, it is checking if `Object` (not an instance of `Object`, but the constructor itself) has as an instance of `Function.constructor` somewhere up its prototype chain.

And, indeed:

```
> Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype
true
> Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype
true
```

This explains why `Object instanceof Function` as well as the reverse.

Answer (score 7):

ALL objects have an internal property called [[Prototype]]. The value of this property is either null or an object and is used for implementing inheritance. If you try to look up a key on an object and it is not found, JavaScript will look for it in the prototype chain.

The Function constructor creates new Function objects (instances of Function constructor). The prototype property is specific to Function objects. The Function constructor is itself a Function object (instance of Function constructor).

When a Function object is used as a constructor, a new object will be created and the new object will have its [[Prototype]] initialized with the prototype property of the constructor.

```
function Dog () {}
var myCrazyDog = new Dog();
myCrazyDog.__proto__ === Dog.prototype // true
```

The language spec is that all objects are instances of Object constructor, and all functions are instances of Function constructor.

**Object instanceof Function is true** because Object is a function and thus is an instance of Function (Object is a Function object - an instance of the Function constructor). Object inherits from Function.prototype.

```
console.log(Object instanceof Function)                         // true
console.log(Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype)            // true
```

**Object instanceof Object is true** because Object inherits from Function.prototype. Since Function.prototype is an object, it inherits from Object.prototype.
**Function instance of Object is true** because Function inherits from Function.prototype. Since Function.prototype is an object, it inherits from Object.prototype.
The prototype chain looks like this:

```
Object ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null
Function ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null

console.log(Object instanceof Object)                               // true
console.log(Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype)                // true
console.log(Object.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype)        // true
console.log(Function instanceof Object)                             // true
console.log(Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype)              // true
console.log(Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype)      // true
```

**Function instanceof Function is true**. Function is an instance of itself (naturally, since it’s a function, and thus an instance of Function). The prototype chain looks like this:

```
Function ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null

console.log(Function instanceof Function)                           // true
console.log(Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype)              // true
console.log(Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype)      // true
```

Thus keep in mind that the Function() and Object() constructors are functions. Since they are functions they are instances of the Function() constructor and inheriting from Function.prototype.
Since Function.prototype is an object, Function.prototype is an instance of Object, thus inheriting from Object.prototype.

```
console.log(Object instance of Function)                    // true
console.log(Function instance of Function)                  // true
console.log(Function.prototype instanceof Object);          // true
```

Answer (score 3):

The source of the confusion in your question lies in the inherent dual nature of functions* in JavaScript (ECMAScript).

Functions in js are both regulars functions and objects at the same time. Think of them as algorithmic **Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde**. They look like objects on the outside but inside they're just your good old js functions with all their quirks, or maybe it's the other way around!

JavaScript is really a tricky business :)

So back to your question, borrowing the syntax appearing on MDN:

`object instanceof constructor`

Applying it on the first statement in your code:

`Object instanceof Function`

Here you have `Object`, a constructor function that's used as an object initializer but since functions lead a double life in js, it has object-specific props and methods attached to it rendering it effectively an object too.

So, the first condition in the statement has been met. We remain to investigate the other condition or operand.

`Function` as you might have noticed is also function constructor but its other object side is of no interest to us now during the execution of this particular statement.

So, the syntactic conditions are both met namely "object" and "constructor". We can now then proceed to investigate their *hereditary* relation and if there's a connection between them.

Since `Object` is a working function itself, it makes a lot of sense to assume that it has its internal prototype prop pointing to the `Function.prototype` object reference since in js **ALL** functions *inherit* their props and methods through that same location `Function.prototype`.

`true` is definitely the **ONLY** expected outcome of this comparison performed by the `instanceof` operator.

For the other case:

`Function instanceof Object`

Since we established already that functions in js have also an object side to them. It makes sense that they got their fancy object-specific *toys* from the `Object.prototype`, and therefore they constitute  *instances* of the Object constructor.

Hope I didn't add to the confusion with my explanation and allegories. :)

*: *Not only functions that lead a double life in js. Almost all data types in js have an object dark side to them that facilitate completing operations and manipulations without any hassle.*

Answer (score 1):

The most badass property is actually that Function is an instance of itself. `Function instanceof Function` returns true.

It is nicely explained in Kannan's *The Surprisingly Elegant Javascript Type Model*, at http://web.archive.org/web/20140205182624/http://vijayan.ca/blog/2012/02/21/javascript-type-model

Quote at the end of the explanation:

> Yes, this means that Function is an instance of itself (naturally, since it’s a function, and thus an instance of Function).  This is something we’ve all been dealing with, knowingly or not, for a long time now – all constructor functions are regular functions and thus instances of Function, and Function itself is just the constructor function for constructing other functions, so it too is an instance of Function.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Very Simple Explanation, Different from all answers**

Both Object and Function are constructors(type of both with return "Function objects") and both are created from Function Constructor. 
The __proto__ property of both these point to 'Function.prototype' object.

QUICK EXPLANATION: __proto__ property of an object(say p1 which is Person type) points to the Constructor's protoype(say Person.prototype) 
Again the __proto__ in the prototype chain points to the object "Object.prototype".

BEFORE READING FURTHER PRINT DETAILS ON CHROME CONSOLE console.dir(Object), console.dir(Function)

KEEP IN MIND, function constructors and also objects so you will see both .prototype and __proto__ properties. In all the instance objects(say p1) you will only find the __proto__ property. The __proto__ is accessor for hidden property [[Prototye]] and best way to get is Object.getPrototypeOf(p1) as __proto__ is depricated.

(p1 instanceof Person) here operator checks if the Constructor Person's prototype is in the prototypal chain of the object p1. take a note that first value is instance object(p1) and second value is a constructor (Person).

Lets analyze => Function instanceof Object.

Function object's __proto__.__proto__ points to Object.prototype , So its true

Lets analyze => Object instanceof Function.

Object object's __proto__ points to Function.prototype, So its true

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is a built-in constructor function for objects. It is therefore a function (an instance of [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)). Functions are objects in JavaScript, it is therefore an object too (an instance of `Object`).