# Why is Array instanceof Object?

Tags: javascript

I was playing with `instanceof` in javascript and I stumbled upon the following.

```
Array instanceof Object
returns true

Object instanceof Array
returns false
```

What is the relationship between Array and Object here ?

Comment: the relationship? this is exactly what `instanceof` told you

Comment: The first and most important thing to understand here is that `Array` and `Object` are two **constructor functions**. The second thing is to understand [how `instanceof` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof). Related question: [Why in JavaScript both “Object instanceof Function” and “Function instanceof Object” return true?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23622695/218196)

Comment: Short answer: `Array instanceof Object` is `true` because functions are objects and every object has `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Between the constructors, the relationship or [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) is:

```
Array -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype
Object -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype
```

The 1st is `true` because a constructor is a `Function` and functions are themselves Objects.

```
Array instanceof Function // true
Object instanceof Function // true

(function () {}) instanceof Object // true
```

Answer (score 2):

You're testing the `Array` constructor.  The `Array` constructor is a function used for creating arrays.  So `Array instanceof Function` is true, and `Array instanceof Object` is true (since all JS objects inherit from the `Object` prototype.  But since this is a constructor function, not an actual array `Array instanceof Array` is false.

`Object` is the Object constructor, which all objects inherit from.  Since its still a function `Object instanceof Function` is true, as is `Object instanceof Object`.

None of that is what you're really meaning (I think) to test.  We can test an actual array (rather than the constructor)

and get `[] instanceof Array` and `[] instanceof Object` to be true (while `[] instanceof Function` is false).  This is because all arrays are arrays, all arrays are objects, but arrays are not functions.

we can also test an object and get

`{} instanceof Object` is true, but `{} instanceof Array` and `{} instanceof Function` are false.

The key things here

1. `Array` is a reference to a constructor function, not an actual array.  Constructor functions are Functions, and all Functions are Objects.
2. An Actual Array is an Array, which means its an Object, but is not a Function.
3. Under the covers `instanceof` is looking up an objects "prototype chain" to find any constructors that it inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

An array is an object, but an object is not an array. Object is a base class in Javascript, if it's not a primitive then it's an object, therefore arrays fall into that. But of  course an object isn't necessarily an array.

Comment: oh ok, need to remember C to understand this.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address the question. In the expression `Array instanceof Object`, there are no arrays, so the statement "an array is an object," while true, does not actually apply.

Comment: This answer misses the fact that the OP is performing a check on the `Array` constructor, not an array *instance*.

Answer (score 0):

Array (first capital letter) is a name of "class object" of all arrays in JavaScript. 
That "class object" is an object so `instanceof Object` for it is `true`.

But Object "class object" is not an array - `Object` has no `Array` class in its inheritance chain.