# JavaScript Object instanceof Function and Function instanceof Object

Tags: javascript, function, object, instanceof

Excuse my noobidity, but I do not really understand the following:

```
Function instanceof Object
```

It returns `true`. OK. I understand that... so `Function` is in fact an object. Rather it is the constructor for any function. So when you create a function you create an object which has a `prototype` that is itself an object and that `prototype` holds the constructor of the function. And it inherits from `Object` because any object is created via `Object` constructor.

But why does

```
Object instanceof Function
```

return `true` as well ?

Comment: `Object` is the constructor for objects, it's a function.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622695/why-in-javascript-both-object-instanceof-function-and-function-instanceof-obj) actually explains why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Object instanceof Function
```

It returns true because `Object` **is** an instance of `Function`. It's the object constructor. Call it as

```
Object({})
```

Looks like a function, doesn't it, and sure enough it is one. Has a `call` method and everything:

```
Object.call(0, {})
```

In the same vein,

```
Number instanceof Function // true
String instanceof Function // true
```

The confusion may arise from the natural tendency to think that `Object instanceof Function` means that objects are instances of functions. No, objects are not instances of functions, and `Object instanceof Function` does not mean that, it means that **a very particular value whose name is `Object`** is an instance of `Function`. `Number instanceof Function` does not mean that numbers are instances of functions, it means that the particular object named `Number`, the constructor for the number type, is an instance of a function, because is is:

```
Number(1)
```

It may be clearer to note that

```
String instanceof String // false
Date   instanceof Date   // false
```

because the `String` constructor is not a string--it's a function.

However,

```
Function instanceof Function // true
```

You may think that's obvious, but it's not because "functions are functions"--it's because the `Function` object is a constructor function (for functions).

By the same token

```
Object instanceof Object // true
```

may also seem obvious, but it's **not** because "objects are objects", but because the value named `Object` is a function which in turn are objects.

Comment: So..when you create a function you actually create an object function. And that object function has a prototype. And that prototype is an object. And it holds the constructor.And all the data you want to initialize.But now I understand that the Function function is a weirdo. Because it creates it's own prototype (as any other function does, so it makes sense), but it inherits from that prototype. And any other function including the big ones:Object,Array,Number,String inherit from this one. On the other hand, those prototypes being objects they inherit from Object. Right?
Thanks.

Comment: That is why Object has all the methods a function does. And that is why any prototype has whatever an object has.
So is it safe to say that all constructors are found in the prototype property of any function object ? And all constructors point back to their respective function objects.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622695/why-in-javascript-both-object-instanceof-function-and-function-instanceof-obj) for an explanation to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

All the in built constructors like Object, Array, String etc are Functions. So Object instanceof Function must hold true.

Now if you try obj = new Object();

then

obj instanceof Function

...it will be false, because what you now have is not a function or a constructor but an object.