# Javascript __proto__, Object and Function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm studying/making personal notes on JavaScript again from scratch and bump into a few things for which I'd like some explanation.

Can someone explain this:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("__proto__"); //True 
Object.prototype.__proto__; //null 

Object.hasOwnProperty("__proto__"); //False 
Object.__proto__; //function(){}
```

Why does it say that Object doesn't have own property `__proto__`, and what is the function that it outputs on the last line?

---

Edit: the below part has been solved here: [Why in JavaScript both "Object instanceof Function" and "Function instanceof Object" return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622695/why-in-javascript-both-object-instanceof-function-and-function-instanceof-obj/23623598#23623598)

Additional question, why are the following statements both true?

```
Function instanceof Object //True 
Object instanceof Function //True
```

Comment: In regard to your additional question: `Function` and `Object` are both functions (“constructors” so to say), and also both objects, because all functions are objects.

Comment: Your additional question has been already in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23623598/1903116) elaborately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A note about `__proto__`

This is not a standard property as of ECMAScript 5. This is not at all defined in the [language specification of ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.io). But all the environments widely support its usage. As it is not part of the language specification, its usage is discouraged and the recommended way to access the internal prototype object is to use [`Object.prototype.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) or [`Object.prototype.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Note 1: [`__proto__` has been standardized only in ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-__proto__-property-names-in-object-initializers).

Note 2: Setting the prototype object with `setPrototypeOf` is supported only in ECMAScript 2015.

---

Now, let's see the reason for each of the lines in your question in the following points.

1. Now, the environments which support `__proto__` have defined them in `Object.prototype` object, as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Since most of the objects inherit from `Object`, they all inherit `__proto__` property as well. That is why `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("__proto__");` returns true.
2. But the value of that is `null`, because [this section](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4) of the language specification says that the internal property `[[Prototype]]` of `Object.prototype` should be `null`
3. `Object.hasOwnProperty("__proto__");` returns `False` because `__proto__` is actually defined on `Object.prototype` and `Object` is just inheriting it. As `__proto__` is not its own property, it is returning `False`.
4. `Object.__proto__` returns `Function` object, because [this section](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3) of the language specification clearly says that the internal `[[Prototype]]` property should be the `Function` object.