# Function object and Object object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, instanceof

I get a true evaluation for the below code:

```
console.log(Function instanceof Object);
```

And I get a true evaluation for the below code as well:

```
console.log(Object instanceof Function);
```

What does this mean? Is javascript telling me that both the Function object and the Object object are sort of on the same hierarchy level? 
Why does both of them evaluate to "true"?

Looking forward to your support.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622695/why-in-javascript-both-object-instanceof-function-and-function-instanceof-obj duplicate