# Javascript instanceof operator function returns itself

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a good explanation why new foo() instanceof foo returns false.

```
function foo() {
  return foo;
}
new foo() instanceof foo;
```

If the function foo was defined as, it returns true as expected

```
function foo(){
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622695/why-in-javascript-both-object-instanceof-function-and-function-instanceof-obj

Comment: It might help to do `const instance = new foo; console.log(instance, instance instanceof foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

The latter doesn't really return `1` as constructor functions are [not allowed to return value types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description). The return value is ignored and what you get is a new `foo` (rather than `1`) which of course is of type `foo`.

On the other hand, the former returns a function itself which is of type `Function`.

```js
function foo() {
  return foo;
}

console.log( new foo() instanceof Function );
// true

function bar() {
   return 1;
}

console.log( new bar() );
// prints {} as new bar() returns an empty object of bar proto
```